# C# simple constructor overload

Tags: c#

I am working on a very simple overloaded constructor exercise, but am running into a no overload taking for parameters found. I thought I have done this correctly, but maybe I am doing something wrong?

```
   namespace A3_Date_StudentWork
    {
        class MyDate
        {      


            private int newMonth;
            private int newDay;
            private int currentMonth;
            private int currentDay;

            public MyDate(int month, int day)
            {
               newMonth = month;
               newDay = day;
            }

            public MyDate(int month, int day, int cmonth, int cday)
            {
                newMonth = month;
                newDay = day;
                currentMonth = cmonth;
                currentDay = cday;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is what my new objects look like from main

```
    MyDate today = new MyDate(todayMonth, todayDay);

    MyDate bday = new MyDate(bdayMonth, bdayDay);

    MyDate combine = new MyDate(bdayMonth, bdayDay, todayMonth, todayDay);
```

It is pretty simple program, all of my variables are int. My entire Main:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int todayMonth = 0;
        int todayDay = 0;
        int bdayMonth = 0;
        int bdayDay = 0;


        Console.WriteLine("What is today's month?");
        Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out todayMonth);
       // Console.WriteLine(todayMonth);

        Console.WriteLine("What is today's date?");
        Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out todayDay);
       // Console.WriteLine(todayDay);

        Console.WriteLine("What is your birth month?");
        Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out bdayMonth);
       // Console.WriteLine(bdayMonth);

        Console.WriteLine("What is your birth date?");
        Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out bdayDay);
       // Console.WriteLine(bdayDay);

        MyDate today = new MyDate(todayMonth, todayDay);
        MyDate bday = new MyDate(bdayMonth, bdayDay);
        MyDate combine = new MyDate(bdayMonth, bdayDay, todayMonth, todayDay);
```

And here is the base class with the constructors

```
    {
class MyDate
{      


    private int newMonth;
    private int newDay;
    private int currentMonth;
    private int currentDay;

    public MyDate(int month, int day)
    {
       newMonth = month;
       newDay = day;
    }

    public MyDate(int month, int day, int cmonth, int cday)
    {
        newMonth = month;
        newDay = day;
        currentMonth = cmonth;
        currentDay = cday;
    }
```

The base class is literally the class MyDate

Comment: Where's your call to create the new object?

Comment: Where's the code where you try to create a `MyDate`?

Comment: Your constructor looks fine, please show us the code where you are creating the instance

Comment: MyDate bday = new MyDate(bdayMonth, bdayDay);
MyDate combine = new MyDate(bdayMonth, bdayDay, todayMonth, todayDay);

Comment: sorry, that didn't come out right

Comment: all of bdayMonth, bdayDay, todayMonth, todayDay should be ints.

Comment: @user3678486, please edit your question to add content. Also show the datatype of the vars you are using to call the constructor.

Comment: Both of my constructors are also in the base class

Comment: Is your question meant to say "running into a no overload taking FOUR parameters found"?

Comment: what base class? you're not inhering from anything

Comment: Which base class, MyDate doesn't inherit from anything (except object that is)

Comment: Might sound random... but have you tried switching your two constructors around in the code? I get the feeling its overlooking your 2 parameter constructor (More of a problem with C than C# but may still become a problem i guess)

Comment: The exact error is "MyDate does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments", I am using visual c# express for my compiler

Comment: @Sayse - yes, I did think of that :) I also tried saving and exiting/re-opening the program.

Comment: Is your main code in a different namespace, which is using a different `MyDate` which does not have the 4-parameter constructor?

Comment: In terms of code, it does look right. I would try deleting a character from your four parameter constructor and re adding it (touching the file)

Comment: They are in the same namespace. I have successful use of this same type of constructor overload in a different exercise, which is why I can't see why this one doesn't work. Is it possible that it is something to do with trying to overload the object class directly?

Comment: This doesn't look as a code problem. More likely for some reason you are either not compiling that version of "MyDate" or you are calling a different version (either because it's not compiling that version or a different namespace or anything).

There's nothing wrong with the code. 

Could you maybe upload your project somewhere?

Comment: Thank you all for the advice, I appreciate it very much. I did find the issue, the MyDate class was reading from a different namespace, so it wasn't recognizing the one I was trying to create as the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Just a piece of advice here in terms of technical.
When you have multiple constructors you should from one constructor call the other one if possible by passing the values. This is also known as 'Constructor Chaining'.

Here's an example based on your code:

```
class MyDate
{
    private int newMonth;
    private int newDay;
    private int currentMonth;
    private int currentDay;

    public MyDate(int month, int day)
       : this(month, day, 0, 0)
    { }

    public MyDate(int month, int day, int cmonth, int cday)
    {
        newMonth = month;
        newDay = day;
        currentMonth = cmonth;
        currentDay = cday;
    }
}
```

In this simple case, when you call the constructor with 2 parameters (month and day) the other parameters will be 0 by default. You can also make parameters nullable so you can assign a null value to it.

Comment: Technical term for this is Constructor Chaining.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the term, but couldn't remember it. :-)

Comment: Correct, but doesn't really answer the question. In fact nobody can really answer the question because the OP didn't provide enough information (yet). This should be a comment.

Comment: I know this should be a comment, but when I place this in a comment it will not be readable. Any suggestions for in the future?

Comment: Not really sure, perhaps on GitHub Gist or something similar?

Comment: Then the code is not visible anymore when the Gist is removed or Github is down, therefore I tought that this was the correct solution.

Comment: As a comment, you should briefly make your point about this.. I.e "You should consider reading about constructor chaining", where constructor chaining is a link to a place to read about it (you can use `[description](link)` to create the link)